# blue screen right after new xp install

Tags: windows-xp, reboot

I just installed XP sp3 on my desktop machine. 
The installing process worked, but now when i try to start the system, after the windows loads it restarts itself.

How can I detect the reason of this self restart?

I get an error message with this error signature:

```
BCCode: 1000007f     BCP1: 0000000F     BCP2: 00000000     BCP3: 00000000
BCP4: 00000000     OSVer: 5_1_2600     SP: 3_0     Product: 256_1
```

What can I do in order to detect and solve the problem?

Many thanks

Comment: Does it happen just after a fresh install ? If not, What have you done after installing ? What programs did you eventually install ?

Comment: Do you actually get a blue screen?  If so, do you see an error message on it?

Comment: @Gnoupi: it is after a fresh install. I didn't install yet any of the drivers or other software besides XP.
@hyperslug: I cannot see the error from the blue screen. I get a blue screen and a fast restart.

Comment: Any chance you can boot to safe mode? (F8 repeatedly on boot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be faulty RAM.

Download a toolkit CD such as Hiren's BootCD, burn it to a CD, boot off the CD, and run any of the memory diagnostic tools in there, such as MemTest+. (WARNING: Memory tests takes awhile, you might want to just switch RAM around).

I recommend these steps :

1. Reset BIOS to "Fail-safe defaults" if you have such an option, if not defaults would do.
2. Run memory test or alternate sticks of RAM if memory test takes too much time.
3. If the memory test passes, test the hard disk.
4. If all else fails, disassemble PC and reassemble PC - it might sound stupid, but it works pretty often for me.

Comment: 3. XP partition was formatted before this install. How can I test the HDD? Many thanks scoopdreams

Comment: heya doug, okay testing the hard drive usually involves wiping the disk clean - and the Hiren's BootCD i referred you to has hard disk diagnostics tools on it too. (sorry I can't link you to the BootCD as it is, erm, not very appropriate.)

the HDD is usually not the issue, leave it as the last resort. Try the RAM and the BIOS first. Also, if you are going to do another format, do not select "NTFS (Quick)", let it do the full format as it will map out any bad sectors.

Hope you get it up soon!

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the bios has hard drive settings for AHCI?  Change the hard drive to "Legacy" mode, and see if that resolves it.  Windows XP (even SP 2) has issues with that...

Answer (score 0):

SATA operations, SATA mode (as above said) generetes many problems. 
Try changing mode to 'native' 'ide' (in bios ofcourse)

Try to pull off and put again RAM, then test them (for ex. Windows Memory Diagnostic)

Boot from Hirens boot CD (bible for pc supporting!) and scan hdd (hdd regenerator for example)

Write what happens.